# Clone Grunt Repository and Run Grunt from there

Tags: gruntjs

Because of proxy restrictions on a work machine, I can't seem to get grunt installed, but I can clone git repositories (don't ask).

I want to clone the [grunt repository](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt) and then create a shell script to just run grunt every time I need it.

What command(s) do I need to run, from the root of the repository, to run grunt?

### Edit

See the error logs below when running without proxy (with proxy idles indefinitely i.e. an entire weekend):

```
$ npm install grunt-cli -g
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dembruja\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-11T15_57_09_186Z-debug.log`
```

Comment: You will need `npm` anyway. Do you have it installed? What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10. It is installed, but it doesn't seem to be able to get through the proxy. Will that make using grunt impossible? I'm trying to run a tool built by some other devs within the organization, and it runs using grunt.

Comment: If you run `npm install grunt-cli -g`, what's the error output?

Comment: Added to main post.

Comment: It seems that you have blocked connections. You can clone the grunt git repo, but if you can't get all the dependencies, it will not work.

Comment: I can clone it on a different machine, install the dependencies with npm, and then zip to repository and copy it to the blocked machine. In fact, I already did that with the other project in order to install its dependencies, which includes grunt. Is there a way to run grunt locally for the project I already copied over, since there is a grunt dependency in the node modules?

Comment: How you're going to install the dependencies with `npm` if `npm` dont have acces to the internet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170871/discussion-between-jaredad7-and-muecas).